# Get value from array by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

How can I get a value in my array object in javascript?

here is my `var array`:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"john jay","phone":"1234567890"}]
```

I tried to do:

```
console.log(array.name);
```

and I also tried:

```
console.log(array["name"]);
```

and I also tried:

```
console.log(array[0].name);
```

and also tried:

```
console.log(array[0]["name"]);
```

and i also tried:

```
var hi = JSON.parse(array);
console.log(hi.['name']);
```

all those gave me the error:

```
undefined
```

please help, thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `array[0].name` works: https://jsfiddle.net/5cdq8x1b/ (as well as with the bracket notation)

Comment: Your options 3 and 4 are correct.

Comment: If this is also related to ajax call make sure the data has arrived before you try accessing it. Can't eat a pizza before it gets delivered